# Automatically generating systems of equations in MATLAB (similar issue in Python)

Tags: matlab

Let's say that I want to solve a system of `N` equations with `N` unknown variables. Assume the equation is of the following general form (I have simplified it greatly, and we can pretend each line is equal to zero).

```
x1 - const(1)
x2 - const(2)
x3 - const(3)
...
xN - const(N)
```

where `x1`, `x2`, ..., `xN` are my variables, and `const` is a vector of length `N` of constants determined earlier in the code. I do not know in advance (i.e. cannot hard-code) how many equations and variables there are, but I still wish to write and solve the system in a general way.

In MATLAB, my current solution is to do the following, where `n_vars` is the number of variables, which my program determines earlier on.

```
sym_vars = sym('x',[1 n_vars]);
for i = 1:n_vars
    eqn(i) = sym_vars(i)-const(i);
end
```

This builds the system of equations. `eqn`, that I showed above. All of the numerical solvers (e.g. `fsolve`, `lsqnonlin`, `ode45`) that I plan to use require the system of equations to be defined as a function handle or as a separate function entirely. I can convert the symbolic expression to a function handle via `matlabFunction` or, if dealing with ODEs, via `odeFunction` to address this.

However, there are two main issues with this approach that I want to resolve. The first is that I do not want to have to make symbolic variables and rely on the symbolic toolbox if I am only performing numerical computations. The second is that if I am solving ODEs, the variables actually have to be `x1(t)`, `x2(t)`, `x3(t)`, ..., `xN(t)` for `odeFunction` to work properly. However, using the same logic as my `sym` approach above to make these variables in a general way leads to a warning because character vectors that aren't valid variable names will not be allowed in future releases.

How can I write a system of equations using function handles instead of symbolic variables (or an equivalent solution)? Surely there must be a way to write a system of equations without doing so manually.

Comment: Well, for the case you presented, it's simply `fun = @(x) x-c;`.

Comment: How so? There are `N` different variables, but yours only shows 1.

Comment: I would want `@(x) [x(1)-c(1),x(2)-c(2),...]`

Comment: If both `x` and `c` are vectors of the same length, `f` will be a vector-valued function.  That idea is the most powerful way to numerically simulate systems.  If `x = [x1;x2;x3;...]` and `c = [c1;c2;c3;...]`, then `f1 = @(x) x-c` will give `[x1-c1;x2-c2;x3-c3;...]`.

Comment: When I do, for example:

`c = [1,2,3,4];
eq=@(x) x-c;
solve(eq,[0,0,0,0]);`

it throws an error because it's expecting one initial condition, not 4 (so, isn't it one variable, not 4?)

Comment: `solve` is symbolic.  Use `fsolve`.

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a vector function like

```
N=5;
const=1:5;
fsolve(@(x)x-const,zeros(1,N))
```

the result is:

```
1.0000    2.0000    3.0000    4.0000    5.0000
```